# Weird error in initializing sparkContext python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been using spark 2.0.1 all this while, but tried to upgrade to a newer version i.e 2.1.1 by downloading the tar file into my local and changing the PATHS.

However, now when i try to run any program, it is failing at initialization of sparkContext. i.e.

```
sc = SparkContext()
```

The entire sample code that I am trying to run is :

```
 import os
 os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/"

 from pyspark import SparkContext
 from pyspark.sql import *
 sc = SparkContext()

 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

 df_tract_alpha= sqlContext.read.parquet("tract_alpha.parquet")
 print (df_tract_alpha.count())
```

The exception I get is at the start itself i.e :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vna/scripts/global_score_pipeline/test_code_here.py", line 47, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext()
  File "/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 182, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 249, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Ubuntu"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

I am not passing Ubuntu anywhere in my variables or my ENV variables as well..

I have also tried changing `sc = SparkContext(master='local')`, Still the issue is the same.

Please help in identifying this issue

Edit: Content of spark-defaults.conf

```
spark.master                     spark://master:7077
# spark.eventLog.enabled           true
# spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory
spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory              8g
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
spark.driver.extraClassPath /opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath /opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering (java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Ubuntu") is likely due to an issue with the PySpark version you're using. This error was a known bug in PySpark 2.1.x caused by the presence of certain strings in /etc/os-release. The issue was resolved in Spark 2.2.0 and later.

AS I can see here, to fix this issue, you have two options:

1. [Recommended] Upgrade to a newer version of Spark (2.2.0 or later):

Simply download the newer version, update the SPARK_HOME environment variable, and adjust the paths accordingly.

2. Apply a workaround for Spark 2.1.1:

This workaround involves modifying a PySpark file to ignore the problematic value.

Open the following file in a text editor:

```
/opt/apps/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/worker.py
```

Find the following code block (around line 25):

```
for key, value in os.environ.items():
    if key.startswith("PYSPARK_GATEWAY_"):
        pair = value.split('=')
        if len(pair) != 2:
            raise Exception("Invalid gateway setting %s=%s" % (key, value))
        gateway_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, int(pair[0]), int(pair[1]))
```

Replace it with:

```
for key, value in os.environ.items():
    if key.startswith("PYSPARK_GATEWAY_"):
        pair = value.split('=')
        if len(pair) != 2:
            raise Exception("Invalid gateway setting %s=%s" % (key, value))
        try:
            gateway_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, int(pair[0]), int(pair[1]))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Save the file and try running your code again.

Remember that the second option is just a workaround for the specific issue, and it's always recommended to upgrade to a newer version of Spark if possible. The newer versions come with bug fixes, performance improvements, and new features.

Here is discussion thread on the Spark user mailing list provides more context and workarounds for the error.

The GitHub issue related to the Py4J error in PySpark 2.1.x: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/17356
This is the pull request that fixed the bug in Spark 2.2.0.

The Spark 2.2.0 Release Notes: https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-2-0.html
These release notes mention the bug fixes and improvements in Spark 2.2.0, including the fix for the aforementioned issue.

The Spark mailing list discussion related to the error: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201705.mbox/%3CCAHVukf9AXuUxQZUvEFfowkQY=3J3Dzk3jyJf_kCnW8dR9nZKjg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your configuration files (e.g. `spark-defaults.conf`)? It could be a parsing error for a field expecting an integers. For example, if you try to set `spark.executor.cores  Ubuntu` you could get that exception.

Comment: I have checked my configs. they seem to be fine, added the content in the question now. I am not even using spark executor cores.

Comment: Even A grep -R "Ubuntu" . in the spark folder did not yield any result

Comment: Weird. I might try using the command-line shell tools just to see if you can open a context. Sometimes the scala one (`spark-shell`) gives better error messages; the pyspark error messages tend to be obscured by the py4j interface.

Comment: Not sure what is the issue is, but with a fresh install on a machine, sparkContexts are creating and working